# Java code not running as planned

Tags: java

This isn't the entire code, just the problem area. (Full code below)

```
if (passLength > 4) {
    System.out.println("Signup alost complete.");

    Random rand = new Random();

    int randm = rand.nextInt(100000) + 1;

    System.out.println(
            "To confirm you are not a robot, please enter this code: "
                    + randm);

    String code = userInput.next();

    if (code.equals(randm)) {
        System.out.println("Thank you, " + userName);
        System.out.println(
                "You may now login. Begin by entering your username");

        if (userInput.equals(userName)) {
            System.out.println("Now please enter you password");
        }

        // Where the rest of the program will go
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("The code entered is incorrect.");
    }

}

else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Password");
}
```

I am making a program where the user makes an account, then later signs in. The part I am having trouble with is a verification to ensure the user is human (they obviously are, but still). After creating their username and password, I generate and print a random int, and they have to type it back.

My problem is that the program always skips to the `else` statement, and prints `"The code entered is incorrect."` Even when I enter it perfectly.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Below is the entire code, just in case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hi! To begin please choose your username.");
    System.out.println("To do this, please enter your username below. ");
    System.out.println("This name must be at least three characters.");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userName = userInput.next();

    int nameLength = userName.length();

    if (nameLength > 2) {

        System.out.println("Now please enter your password.");
        System.out
                .println("This password must be at lease five characters");

        String passWord = userInput.next();

        int passLength = passWord.length();

        if (passLength > 4) {
            System.out.println("Signup alost complete.");

            Random rand = new Random();

            int randm = rand.nextInt(100000) + 1;

            System.out.println(
                    "To confirm you are not a robot, please enter this code: "
                            + randm);

            String code = userInput.next();

            if (code.equals(randm)) {
                System.out.println("Thank you, " + userName);
                System.out.println(
                        "You may now login. Begin by entering your username");

                if (userInput.equals(userName)) {
                    System.out.println("Now please enter you password");
                }

                // Where the rest of the program will go
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("The code entered is incorrect.");
            }

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }

    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Username");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a String with an integer, which can't be the same obviously.

```
int randm = rand.nextInt(100000) + 1;
...
String code = userInput.next();
if  (code.equals(randm))
```

To solve the problem you could convert the integer to a String and compare the strings (or the other way).

```
String randm = String.valueOfrand.nextInt(100000) + 1;
...
String code = userInput.next();
if  (code.equals(randm)) // Comparing string now
```

Edit : As @Pshemo pointed out, `int code = userInput.nextInt();` will do the work given that you compare the integers with `==`.

Comment: We can also use `int code = userInput.nextInt();` and `if (code == randm)`

Comment: Indeed, this is an even simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have not clue how I could have missed that.

Comment: To make the code more robust, `userInput.nextInt()` should (always) be preceded by a call to [`userInput.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) (e.g. `while (!userInput.hasNextInt()) { userInput.next(); }`). Otherwise, you need to prepare for handling a possible `InputMismatchException` that gets thrown by `nextInt()` if the user enters non-integer input.

Answer (score 1):

It's because randm is int and code is String. So the code `if (code.equals(randm))` always results to false.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a string and an integer.
Trying taking the input as an integer instead of a String.
`String code = userInput.next();`

Instead use:

```
int code= userInput.nextInt();
if(code==randm)
```

Or you could convert the integer to a String as well